# How to select rows with 4-byte UTF-8 chars in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, unicode, utf-8, plsql

I need to detect whether my table has 4-byte UTF-8 characters and delete them if any.
I tried following SQLs, but they return error `ORA-12726: unmatched bracket in regular expression`. All brackets are matched, so error is incorrect.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(asdaasd', 
  '[' 
  || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('010000', 'UTF8') 
  || '-' 
  || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('01FFFF', 'UTF8') 
  || ']', '') 
from dual;

select REGEXP_REPLACE('asdaasd', 
  '[' 
  || chr(to_number('010000', 'xxxxxx')) 
  || '-' 
  || chr(to_number('01FFFF', 'xxxxxx')) 
  || ']', '') 
from dual;
```

What is wrong with these queries?

Do you know how to find rows by character code points range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the UNISTR function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions224.htm#SQLRF06154); the  character is [codepoint U+2070E](http://codepoints.net/U+2070E), which in UTF-16 is D841DF0E. As the documentation notes:

> Supplementary characters are encoded as two code units, the first from the high-surrogates range (U+D800 to U+DBFF), and the second from the low-surrogates range (U+DC00 to U+DFFF).

Which means you can represent it with:

```
select unistr('\D841\DF0E') from dual;

UNISTR('\D841\DF0E')
--------------------
```

You can then use UNISTR to construct your range:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('asdaasd', 
  '[' 
  || UNISTR('\D800\DC00') 
  || '-' 
  || UNISTR('\DBFF\DFFF') 
  || ']', '') 
from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('ASDAASD','['||UNISTR('\D800\DC00')||'-'||UNISTR('\DBFF\DFFF')||']','')
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
asdaasd
```

Assuming you want to exclude all supplementary characters; you can adjust the range if you have a more narrow focus.

Comment: I am getting a ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression when I try the exact same expression in the answer!

Comment: posted a new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499669/how-to-detect-4byte-utf8-characters-in-oracle

Answer (score 2):

maybe this not what exacly you need but to solve the error ora-12726 use this query

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('asdaasd', 
  '\[' 
  || chr(to_number('010000', 'xxxxxx')) 
  || '-' 
  || chr(to_number('01FFFF', 'xxxxxx')) 
  || '\]', '') 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you convert from raw to char you must supply the octet sequence in the chosen encoding. What you supply are the Unicode code points but not their utf8 encoding. To get that, you can use online tools like [this one](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.html) or a [code table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). E.g. `U+010000` is represented as `f0908080`in utf-8 (range extended to `U+010000`-`U+02FFFF` to include source character).

So in the sample case, use the following:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('asd'||UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('F0A09C8E', 'AL32UTF8')||'aasd', 
  '[' 
  || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('F0908080', 'AL32UTF8') 
  || '-' 
  || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('F0AFBFBF', 'AL32UTF8') 
  || ']', '') 
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, it doesn't replace that unicode symbol, even if I extend second char in range to 'F48083BF'. The output is still 'asdaasd'

Comment: @Barataliba The character to be replaced falls outside the range of the original regexp specified, range extended.

Comment: Oracle Character set `UTF8` is **not** the same as commonly known encoding [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Oracle Character set `UTF8` means [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) encoding. For "real" UTF-8 you have to use Oracle character set `AL32UTF8`, thus you must use `UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(..., 'AL32UTF8')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for the info, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer `RAW_TO_CHAR`, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('asdaasd', 
  '[' 
  || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('F0908080', 'AL32UTF8')
  || '-' 
  || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('F48FBFBF', 'AL32UTF8') 
  || ']', '') 
FROM dual;
```

Oracle Character set `UTF8` is not the same as commonly known encoding [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Oracle Character set `UTF8` means [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) encoding. For  UTF-8 you have to use Oracle character set `AL32UTF8`

`U+01FFFF` is not the biggest Unicode codepoint, your string may contain "" (`U+02F8D3 CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-2F8D3`). The biggest possible Unicode codepoint is `U+10FFFF`, which is equal to `UNISTR('\DBFF\DFFF')`(as provided by Alex Poole's answer), resp. `UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('F48FBFBF', 'AL32UTF8')`.

btw, for the conversion I use this page: [Unicode code converter](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/)