# How to detect 4byte UTF8 characters in Oracle

Tags: oracle, utf-8

We have seen 4byte UTF-8 characters stored in oracle. We need to detect how many rows have such characters in a particular column.

Tried the recommendation given here - [UTF-16 supplementary characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720830/how-to-select-rows-with-4-byte-utf-8-chars-in-oracle-db/34722038#34722038) but that didn't work for me. It throws an error - ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression. Tried the other answers too. None of them work.

Oracle documented the possible hex code ranges for UTF-8 in table B-2 in this page [Unicode Character Set](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/appunicode.htm#CACHBDGH). I am trying to detect any character that falls in row 5 or 6 of that table ( "Supplementary characters: Additional Chinese, Japanese, and Korean characters; historic characters; musical symbols; mathematical symbols" OR "Private Use Area #2"  )

Is there a regular expression I can use to detect such rows?

```
select count(*) from mytable where regexp_like(mycolumn, expression);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a reproducible example, including a set-up with sample data and the actual query that throws the error. Preferably your original and using both of Wenfried's versions from a comment, using the correct UCS-2 values and raw-to-char. Both of those seem to work so we need to understand what you are doing differently to get the error you are seeing. Also include your DB version and patch level, and maybe your characterset.

Comment: [Quick DB FIddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9b1060091b465d0ab21928d6b9dbe2c0) showing what you seem to be doing, working...

Comment: For the life of me, I couldn't figure out why I was getting ORA-12728. I finally gave up on finding the characters, instead I excluded the characters - 1,2,3 byte UTF8 and checked if anything remains. Like `select count(*) from mytable where length(rawtohex(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, ‘[’ ||CHR(32)|| ‘-’ ||CHR(122)|| ‘|' || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(‘C280’, ‘AL32UTF8’)|| ‘-’ || UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(‘EFBFBF’, ‘AL32UTF8’)|| ‘]’ , ‘’)))>0`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

May be you did something wrong with regexp building: 
There is short example.

```
-- create table: 
create table tmp_a as 
select unistr('\D841\DF0E') col from dual;
insert into tmp_a(col)
values(UNISTR('\D800\DC00'));
insert into tmp_a(col)
values(UNISTR('\D800\DC01'));
insert into tmp_a(col)
values(UNISTR('\D803\DC03'));
insert into tmp_a(col)
values(UNISTR('\041f'));
insert into tmp_a(col)
values('a');
insert into tmp_a(col)
values('b');


-- then check. There is should be 7 rows and only 4 should pass then "check"
select col, dump(col) , regexp_instr(col, '['||UNISTR('\F090\8080')||'-'||UNISTR('\F48F\BFBF')||']') as check from  tmp_a ;


-- finaly we could build next query with regexp_like as in your example 
select count(*) 
  from tmp_a 
 where regexp_like(col, '['||UNISTR('\F090\8080')||'-'||UNISTR('\F48F\BFBF')||']')
```

It works on Oracle 11.2.0.4 and 12.2.0.1

Comment: Used `dump(col, 1016) , regexp_instr(col, '['||UNISTR('\F090\8080')||'-'||UNISTR('\F48F\BFBF')||']') as check` and I see the following `HEX Typ=1 Len=25 CharacterSet=UTF8: bunch of codes, f0,a3,be,b7, bunch of codes` and check as 0. I was hoping it would find the f0,a3,be,b7

Comment: Can you please add the result of the query to your answer? - `select col, dump(col, 1016) , regexp_instr(col, '['||UNISTR('\F090\8080')||'-'||UNISTR('\F48F\BFBF')||']') as check from  tmp_a ;`

Comment: This is the character I am trying to find - [4-byte UTF](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=F0+A3+BE+B7&mode=bytes)

Comment: `UNISTR` expects UTF-16 code points, not UTF-8. You must use `UNISTR('\D800\DC00')||'-'||UNISTR('\DBFF\DFFF')` instead of `UNISTR('\F090\8080')||'-'||UNISTR('\F48F\BFBF')`. Or, if you insist on UTF-8 use `UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR('F0908080', 'AL32UTF8')||'-'||UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR('F48FBFBF', 'AL32UTF8')`

Comment: Used `UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR('F0908080', 'AL32UTF8')||'-'||UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR('F48FBFBF', 'AL32UTF8')`. This gives ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression!

Comment: Please show us your full query. You should not get an ORA-12728.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to look for surrogates. High surrogate is from `U+D800`-`U+DBFF`, low surrogate is from `U+DC00`-`U+DFFF`.

This one should also work, is looks for the low surrogate:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ASCIISTR(mycolumn), '\\D[C-F]')
```

Comment: The count I got is much higher than the actual 4 byte characters that exist... Possibly picking up non 4byte UTF as well.

Comment: Do you have an example for a row which you do not expect but is  returned anyway?

Comment: regular street addresses. Something like `9/5 xyz Road Garden`

Comment: `9/5 xyz Road Garden` in UTF-8 is even just 1 byte for each character. It is plain ASCII and far away from 4 bytes!