# How to check character is Arabic in SQL oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I was looking for function or way to cross check character is Arabic.

Any help will be appreciated.

I am using oracle SQL & tried below sql Query

select count(*)
from dual
where regexp_like('أ', '['||UNISTR('\0600')||'-'||UNISTR('\06FF')||']')

But it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Arabic Script: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode

The unicode character range for Arabic is: 0600–06FF

(0600–06FF, 256 characters)

---

Knowing the above, you would check your character to see if it's within the unicode range above, if it is, it's an Arabic character.

Comment: how to get Unicode of Arabic charter stored in variable or db??

Comment: You could probably use regex to get what you need 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499669/how-to-detect-4byte-utf8-characters-in-oracle

Comment: I tried same way & below query does not works 

select count(*) 
  from dual 
 where regexp_like('أ', '['||UNISTR('\0600')||'-'||UNISTR('\06FF')||']')

Comment: if we reduce range then it may work but not for all characters , kindly suggest.

Comment: You should edit your main question and provide more details on your environment. 

is a SQL query the only thing available to you? are you able to use Python or Golang to query the DB and perhaps do your processing/checking outside the DB?